# Audio output annoying noise, 22.04

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04, noise

i have an annoying noise from my laptop speakers, it stops when i stop the daemon, but i want to fix this so i can use audio normaly.

ubuntu 20.04 didn't had this issue.

```
pulseaudio -v
```

didnt't showed any verbose when the noise starts nor stops.

i deactivated the

```
module-suspend-on-idle
```

at /etc/pulse/default.pa , since it is supposed that this problems is due to energy management.. but the problem persists.

any clue?

Comment: Hi I have this issue too Could you fix it?

Comment: yes, down in the post is the modification that worked

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

anything else than this didn't worked:

instal tlp (this administrates energy)

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tlp
```

to enable and configure tlp, first open the conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/tlp.conf
```

then uncomment (delete the #) and set

```
TLP_ENABLE=1

SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0

SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0
```

the idea is to use tlp to disable power saving, that seems to be causing the noise.

then reboot the computer

```
reboot
```

and the noise should stopped, if not check that the parameters you modified are ok by means of

```
sudo tlp-stat -c
```

Comment: Not even this worked for me. Tried everything else mentioned around here. Sound just sleeps whenever there is quiet, even during a youtube video.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the root user:

```
sudo su
```

Check the power save setting for the sowund card:

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

If the out put is 1, like below, changing this may solve your problem:

```
$ cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
1
```

Set the option to 0 for the current session to test the fix:

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_usb_audio/parameters/power_save
```

If it works, you need to change it permanently:

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo nano audio_disable_powersave.conf
```

In the nano editor, add the following line to the file:

```
options snd_hda_intel power_save=0
```

[image: nano, disable sound card power save mode]

Save the file and exit using:

```
Ctrl+O
Enter
Ctrl+X
```

Note 1: For an USB sound card you can use *snd_usb_audio* instead of *snd_hda_intel*.

Note 2: Making this change will slightly affect the battery life of a Laptop and the power consumption of a Destop

This worked for me on a laptop running Ubuntu 22.10 which kept putting out a buzzing sound a few seconds after any sound output from any application stopped.

Comment: The answer is from here: https://itsfoss.com/buzzing-noise-speaker-linux/